# DRILL as a custom service with HDP 2.6 : java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hadoop2, ambari, apache-drill

I am installing Drill with HDP 2.6 and while going through the installation,the screen stuck at one screen in choosing slave agent .

In the log file:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashSet cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.StackAdvisorResourceProvider.prepareStackAdvisorRequest(StackAdvisorResourceProvider.java:110)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ValidationResourceProvider.createResources(ValidationResourceProvider.java:81)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl.createResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:298)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.persistence.PersistenceManagerImpl.create(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:97)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.CreateHandler.persist(CreateHandler.java:37)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.BaseManagementHandler.handleRequest(BaseManagementHandler.java:73)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseRequest.process(BaseRequest.java:144)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:126)
    at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:90)
```

Earlier i have succesfully tested with HDP 2.5 and the drill custom service scripts has been downloaded from https://github.com/dvergari/ambari-drill-service.

Please help me resolve this issue.
HDP:2.6
Ambari:2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with this git repo...Change **metainfo.xml** as below...

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<metainfo>
    <schemaVersion>2.0</schemaVersion>
    <services>
        <service>
            <name>DRILL</name>
            <displayName>Drill</displayName>
            <comment>Schema-free SQL Query Engine</comment>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
            <components>
                <component>
                    <name>DRILL_MASTER</name>
                    <displayName>Drill Master</displayName>
                    <category>MASTER</category>
                    <cardinality>1+</cardinality>
                    <commandScript>
                        <script>scripts/drill.py</script>
                        <scriptType>PYTHON</scriptType>
                        <timeout>10000</timeout>
                    </commandScript>
                    <configFiles>
                      <configFile>
                        <type>xml</type>
                        <fileName>drill-env.xml</fileName>
                        <dictionaryName>drill-env</dictionaryName>
                      </configFile>
                      <configFile>
                        <type>xml</type>
                        <fileName>drill-override.xml</fileName>
                        <dictionaryName>drill-override</dictionaryName>
                      </configFile>
                      <configFile>
                        <type>xml</type>
                        <fileName>drill-ambari-config.xml</fileName>
                        <dictionaryName>drill-ambari-config</dictionaryName>
                      </configFile>           
                    </configFiles>
                </component>                
            </components>
          <configuration-dependencies>
            <config-type>drill-env</config-type>
            <config-type>drill-override</config-type>
            <config-type>drill-ambari-config</config-type>
          </configuration-dependencies>         
        </service>
    </services>
</metainfo>
```

`